# Does revenue equal gross profit for info product business?

Tags: income, income-statement

For a small online business that has no employees or inventory and only sales info products, does revenue equal gross profits since there is no cost to make the info product?

Comment: The revenue in this case may be equal to the gross profit if there are truly no cost of goods sold (COGS); however, it would **not** be equal to _operating profit_. That is, _gross profit less operating expenses_. That includes most of the costs Rick mentioned in his answer—advertising, overhead, and maintenance to name a few—expenses not directly related to any one sale.

Answer (score 5):

What about web-hosting fees? Cost of Internet service? Cost of computer equipment to do the work? Amortized cost of development? Time for support calls/email? Phone service used for sales? Advertising/marketing expenses?

Look hard--I bet there are *some* costs.

Comment: All operating expenses and not direct cost of making the course.

Comment: Right. I wasn't reading carefully enough. As @PJS1987 points out in his comment, if there is truly no cost of goods, then the answer to your original question is "yes". Net profit is, of course, a different matter.

Comment: Can you append to your answer?  I will accept.